# Unwanted Block Thread causing Tomcat Failure

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I have a web application running on Tomcat 7.x
The application stops running once there is a significant load on the server.
On looking into the thread dump I have observed the below stacktrace occuring (which is not related to my applications code). Any pointer for the probable reasons

```
"ajp-bio-26642-exec-181" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0ae2a800 nid=0x3508 waiting for monitor entry [0x3a5ec000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:354)
    - waiting to lock <0x7a7095b8> (a org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    - locked <0xe40ab0d0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you using some resources or some code in a synchronized manner, there is some dead lock it seems

Comment: Yes I am but the application was running fine until recent, only thing we changed was closing some open database connections.

Comment: You are using which database MySql, Sqlite or something other

Comment: Its using the Oracle 11g database

Comment: Are you sure the only thing changes was closing connection nothing more... ? Can you just revert changes and try if this problem does not occurs

Comment: Yes, pretty sure of doing just those changes :)

Comment: Also reverted back to the changes but the situation is same :(

Comment: So you got the same problem after reverting back the changes

Comment: Yes. Pasting the Thread dump for Runnable thread too where I am seeing lock
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3685)
 - locked <0x7a617808> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1376)
 at com.updatePages(Service.java:264)
 - locked <0x883dc868> (a com.ManagerBean)
 at com.Data(MyList.java:1095)
 at com.MyList.endTag(MyList.java:58)

Comment: It is helpful when posting stack traces with lines numbers if you also mention the exact version of the software (in this case Apache Tomcat) that you are using. Code changes over time and figuring our which line of code is being called can take time when you have almost 50 different versions to check.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the full thread dump. I can see where the requests are getting blocked but I need the full stack of the thread holding the lock on object 0x3a5ec000 to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing at you logs posted in comment, I suspect there is some problem how you handle your connection to database?
Since there is no actual code posted, Just search for answers to some of these questions may be it can lead you to proper direction,

1. Look at your connection settings.
2. Do you use autocommit?
3. What is the maximum amount of opencursors in Oracle?
4. How do you handle connections. Do you have a connection pool, or do you create a connection whenever needed and close them on fly?
5. Which Oracle driver is being used? [More info](http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/tag/stuck-thread/)
6. Do you use UCP? If yes look at [this link](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2568046)

For more information how you can analyze the thread dumps [what-to-look-for-in-java-thread-dumps](http://j2eedebug.blogspot.in/2008/12/what-to-look-for-in-java-thread-dumps.html) or [how-analyze-java-thread-dumps](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-thread-dumps)

Comment: 1. We connect using JNDI 2. autocommit is not set in code and server either 3. 400 maxActive connections per instance over 3 instances 4. The application fetches connection via datasource configured on application server(Tomcat). 5. ojdbc14.jar in the application WAR but ojdbc6 in Tomcat(7.X) Server Lib. 6. Yes we do use UCP